# Finite Union of Countable sets is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have not studied the axiom of choice, I know how to prove that the union of two countable sets is countable and I want to use that a proceed by induction, but I'm not sure if my argument is okay. 
Let A and B be countable sets then since we know $A \cup B$ is countable the base case holds true. Then let us suppose it true for $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}A_{i}$ and prove it for $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$

Way 1:
By induction hypothesis $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} A_i$  is countable so lets denote it by $A$, then $A \cup A_n$ is just the union of two sets which is again true by the base case. Pretty sure this is wrong.

Way 2: By induction hypothesis $A = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} A_i$  is countable and there exist bijection $f: \Bbb{N} \rightarrow A$, there also exists a bijection 
$g: \Bbb{N} \rightarrow A_n$ Then define

$$
h(n) =
\begin{cases}
f(k),  & \text{if } n = 2k \\[2ex]
g(k), & \text{if } n = 2k -1
\end{cases}
$$
We have a bijection .

Comment: Way 1 works fine.

Comment: You may be interested to know that even a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: How do you know that union of two countable sets is countable? Have you proven that? If not, you need to.

Comment: @JustinBenfield You my be interested to know that in the general case some form of the axiom of choice is required to prove that a countable union of countable sets is countable. It's not needed for the case of finite unions.

Comment: @BrianO: Are you sure? Wouldn't you be able to exploit the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ is well ordered by $\leq$ along with induction to prove that countable union is countable without axiom of choice?

Comment: As Justin said way $1$ looks fine. Just FYI, there is a direct way of proving this - if $A_i$ are countable sets, we can enumerate (via bijection from $\omega$) their elements as $x_j^i$ where $j=1,2,\cdots$ and the map $(x_{j_1}^1,\cdots,x_{j_n}^n)\mapsto 2^{j_1}3^{j_2}\cdots p_n^{j_n}$ is an injection where $p_n$ is $n^{\text{th}}$ prime

Comment: @JustinBenfield No, basically because, even if you know that, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, the set $$\mathcal F_n:=\{f:A_n\to\Bbb N\text{ such that }f\text{ is bijective}\}$$ is not empty, *in general* you need the choice to prove that there exists a sequence $$f_{(\bullet)}:\Bbb N\to \bigcup\limits_{n\in\Bbb N}\mathcal F_n$$ such that $f_n\in \mathcal F_n$. Or in other words, you need the choice to prove that you can assign to each $n$ a bijection $f_n:A_n\to\Bbb N$. You can work around it and pull it off in the finite case.

Comment: @JustinBenfield In fact, there are models of ZF where $\omega_1$ (and even $\mathbb{R}$) is a countable union of countable sets.  Note that having a family of countable sets does not mean that you have a family of sets indexed by $\mathbb{N}$; to get the latter from the former, you need the axiom of choice.

Comment: But isn't the definition of countable set that there exists a bijection between that set and the naturals? Hence if I know each set is countable I am therefore guaranteed some bijection $f_n:A_n\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$. Then I can use the argument that proves $\mathbb{Q^+}$ countable on $i$'s in $A_j$ and the $j$'s to construct my bijection (if they are disjoint unions at least).

Comment: Looks like you only need the axiom of *countable* choice, not the full power of AC: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Countable_Union_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable

Comment: @JustinBenfield Yes I'm sure :) and yes, you need at least countable choice. (As I said, *some* amount of choice.)